# Close browser tab

Tags: javascript

I have a page that tells users to go to their email and click verification link. When they do, the link in the email message opens a new tab, so now the user has two tabs open, both related to email, which is a bit confusing.

- Is there any chance to have them click the link in their email and open confirmation within the first tab or
- Open the new tab but at the same time close the original tab?

There's gotta be way with JS, I hope.

Comment: No, not really. The link is external to the web browser so this is the web browser doing what web browsers do. It's out of your hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you could run a Javascript in your first tab that pings your server every 10 seconds or so, to check if the account was confirmed.

If it was, then the page redirects itself to the new user's dashboard (or some other "main account page").

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('/api/is_confirmed.php').then(
        function(response){
            if (response.status_code == '200')
                window.location = '/dashboard.php';
        }
    );
}, 10000);
```

I would advise against `self.close()`ing the window. Do not interfere with the user's control of the browser tabs. Having tabs suddenly disappear by themselves is unexpected for the user and annoying at best, frightening at worst.

Answer (score 0):

You can check periodically from the 1st tab if the email got activated then close it  `window.close()` , thus the remaining open tab would be the 2nd one, typically, you would implement something like that using setInterval and an ajax request to your server backend to check if the email was activated or not yet.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is:

1- Instead of having a link to your page in that email, put a link to a special page that changes a database value then closes itself.

2- On the main page, have a thread constantly poll that database value and as soon as you see the change, update the page with ajax (or refresh) then bring the broser on top of other windows.